# Определение нового участника если участники скрыты

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

Есть группа в телеграмм и бот (админ права есть) не реагирует на вступление новых участников, потому-что участники скрыты, если их открыть, то все нормально.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то без открытия участников приветствовать новых участников?

````
async def handler_new_member(message: types.Message):
    pass```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бот не сможет получить информацию участников группы, если профили скрыты. Тг сам не дает такие доступы

Если все же очень надо приветствовать новых участников, придется просить участников открыть свои профили в настройках телеграмма. Тогда можно использовать методы апи, такие как getChatMember, чтобы получить информацию о новых участниках и приветствовать их автоматически.
выглядит так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def handle_new_member(message: Message):
    for member in message.new_chat_members:
        user_id = member.id
        user = await bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, user_id).user
        # Получаем инфу о новом участнике через api
        # Если профиль скрыт, инфы недоступна
        # Если инфа доступна, приветствуем пользователя
        if user:
            name = user.first_name
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Добро пожаловать, {name}!')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы не так поняли мой вопрос. 
Скрыты не сами профили, а скрыты учатсники в группе. То есть не видно кто находится в группе.

Comment: так все легче еще, никак)если участники скрыты, бот не видит их тоже

Comment: Ответ конечно огорчил. Но спасибо.